# Java JDBC ActiveDirectoryAuthentication Azure SQLServer failing with 401 /adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport Exception

Tags: java, sql-server, azure

I am trying to run a Java 1.8 Update 192 application on an Azure Windows Server 2016 virtual machine which is using the Microsoft SQLServer JDBC 7.2.1.jre8 driver to connect to an SQLServer managed instance database using a user authenticated against an ActiveDirectory instance and running the application as that user i.e. using Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated.

I am getting the exception:

> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 401 for URL :
>   https://xxx/adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerADAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthTokenIntegrated(SQLServerADAL4JUtils.java:113)
>           ... 26 more Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 401 for URL :
>   https://xxx/adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerADAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthTokenIntegrated(SQLServerADAL4JUtils.java:106)
>           ... 26 more 3119 [main] INFO zzz  - Database connection failed: Failed to authenticate the user  in Active Directory
>   (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated).

I am not a .NET developer and have no knowledge of ActiveDirectory authentication configuration, Windows domains etc.

The above exception error messages mean nothing to me. What do they mean ?

I can connect to the database using an SQLServer authenticated user and password but the requirement is to use Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated.

Comment: Also I can successfully connect using SQL Server Management Studio using Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated running as the ActiveDirectory user I am supposed to use. What is SSMS doing that the Java app is not ?

Answer (score 0):

The following exception indicates that the authentication with ActiveDirectory failed.

```
com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL : https://xxx/adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by explicitly including the driver jar and dll in the command line:

java -cp .;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC DRIVER 7.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_7.2\enu\mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar" -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC DRIVER 7.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_7.2\enu\auth\x64" -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties -jar MyJar.jar

I am using:

```
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource ds =
            new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource();
    ds.setServerName(dbServerName);
    ds.setPortNumber(dbServerPort);
    ds.setDatabaseName(dbaseName);
    ds.setAuthentication("ActiveDirectoryIntegrated");
```

Thanks